# How to use WF4 activity to wait for an event?

Tags: .net, event-handling, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I found that you can use Pick activity and this activity will contain a few PickBranches, each of which contains a Trigger and an Action. How do I tie the Trigger activity to any .NET event? for example, [Timer.Tick event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick.aspx), Key pressed event, or perhaps my own event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't directly. A WF activity can use a bookmark and wait for that bookmark to be resumed. Now you are free to resume a bookmark based on some .NET event or a key press but you still have to code that part.

Comment: how about the pickbranch activity? do I can only specify a custom activity as Trigger?

Comment: You can also use a Delay of Receive activity. Or in theory any other activity as the criteria is the first trigger to complete.